# Is '(ulong) 1' slower than '1ul' in c#?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, ulong

I've been using `(ulong) 1` to represent 1bit in 64bit-data type. I wonder if `(ulong) 1` does some sort of type conversion and takes more time than `1ul`.

Just being curious if this makes any difference. I thought both of them are just exactly same in performance. Is this correct, or is `(ulong) 1` actually slower?

Comment: exactly the same.

Comment: You should know that attempting to learn billions of rules for micro-optimizing your code will not work out in the long run. The chances that *this line of code* is critical to the performance of your application is zero. If, by some bizarre chance it's not zero, you would measure your specific scenario and pick the winner. Any other time, pick what you find most readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no runtime type conversion will happen when you use casting with compile time constant and [build-in numeric conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions) (i.e. `(ulong) 1`) since compiler can handle such things and both approaches should result in the same IL/ASM. For example:

```
var x = 1ul;
var y = (ulong)1;
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Will produce [the same IL](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQOBuAhgE4AEAHiQLwnoCuEA3PsSQJ5UkAU9A9gHYBzAJTom2ZOgCcnMkLETprOUA==):

```
.maxstack 1
    .entrypoint
    .locals init (
    [0] uint64 x,
    [1] uint64 y
)

IL_0000: ldc.i4.1
IL_0001: conv.i8
IL_0002: stloc.0
IL_0003: ldc.i4.1
IL_0004: conv.i8
IL_0005: stloc.1
IL_0006: ldloc.0
IL_0007: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(uint64)
IL_000c: nop
IL_000d: ldloc.1
IL_000e: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(uint64)
IL_0013: nop
IL_0014: ret
```

From the language specification - [12.23 Constant expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1223-constant-expressions):

> Only the following constructs are permitted in constant expressions:
>
> - Literals (including the `null` literal).
> - ...
> - Cast expressions.
> - ...

So basically in this case `(ulong) 1` will be treated as constant as the integer literal `1ul`.

Also see the [Integer literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#integer-literals) section of the docs.

Comment: Note also that the `conv.i8` is also optimized away by the Jitter in both cases.